# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from a character string

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, datetime

This code was working yesterday but not now. I haven't changed anything... Why is that and how can i fix it?

```
    {
        var info = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Turkey Standard Time");
        DateTimeOffset localServerTime = DateTimeOffset.Now;
        DateTimeOffset istanbulTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(localServerTime, info);

        con.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE BilgisayarDuyuru SET date='" + istanbulTime + "'  WHERE id='" + id + "'";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();            
    }
```

Comment: you'll probably have to clarify your question along with adding a few examples of things you tried in order to receive any help. You can always update your question. Welcome to stack overflow, recommended reading: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Did your data change under you?

Comment: No i didn't change anything. But now it's working. Still not changed anything. Should i delete this question ?

Comment: Not working now means..r u getting any error..please more specific..

Comment: @Sachu Now it's not working again. Not working means it gives the error which in the title :)

Comment: @wanxpy Sorry i didn't give more concentration on the heading :)

Comment: @wanxpy do you want to save the offset value that contain + or - then it cannot be done in the datetime datatype column you need to change the data type of column to varchar

Comment: @Sachu Data tyoe of column is datetimeoffset(7)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77673/discussion-between-sachu-and-wanxpy).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok try this

```
{
 var info = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Turkey Standard Time");
 DateTimeOffset localServerTime = DateTimeOffset.Now;
 DateTimeOffset istanbulTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(localServerTime, info);
string s1 = istanbulTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ffffff zzz");
con.Open();
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE BilgisayarDuyuru SET date='" + s1+ "'  WHERE id='" + id + "'";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  con.Close();            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday was the 12th today is the 13th. Are you sure that month and day are not being mixed up? After all I'm sure that in Instanbul you only have 12 months?